# PHP, strip_tags stripping \n in text area. How to stop it?

Tags: php, string-formatting, strip-tags

I would like to be able to accept `\n` or `\r\n` and convert them to `<br />` for use in the page. Although when a user submits a text area with new paragraphs, the `strip_tags` function seems to strip them right out. Anything I can do to keep these in the string?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`nl2br`](http://php.net/nl2br) to add the `BR` line break element to line break character sequences:

```
$html = nl2br($plain);
```

Note that the `BR` elements are just added:

```
nl2br("foo\nbar") === "foo\n<br />bar"
```

And to prevent [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) to remove `P` and `BR` tags, specify them in the second parameter:

```
$clean = strip_tags($html, '<p><br>');
```

Comment: that worked. Thanks EVERYONE for all the help, so much appreciated!