# Strip HTML string but don't lose line breaks

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I have a string which contains a lot of HTML (HTML email body).

What I want to do is lose all the HTML but keep the line breaks, I tried `strip_tags()` but this didn't work out for me, it makes the string just 1 line.

After this has been done, I want to echo only the first 5 lines from this string.

Anyone got an idea?

Update:

```
$string = strip_tags($string, '<p><br><br />');
```

Seems to be working, now I have to select the first 5 lines from the string, anyone an idea?

Update:
Array keeps giving a few empty values.
I managed to remove the empty ones but the array doesn't restart the counting.
Array looks like this now:

```
Array ( [8] =>

Dit is een nieuwe test met meerdere regels.
[9] =>

Dit is regel nummer 2.
[10] =>

Dit is regel nummer 3.
```

But it should start counting at 0 again.

`array_filter() array_merge()` etc. do not work.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069916/php-strip-tags-stripping-n-in-text-area-how-to-stop-it ?

Comment: @trainoasis I'm very sure. Is this possible?

Comment: @trainoasis Thanks, updated my question.

Comment: stop using php ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it now, didn't use the email message anymore but get the message data from the DB, now I can strip the string and explode, starts counting at 0 now!

Thanks for the thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

Use [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) with a second parameter, like this: `strip_tags($html, '<p><br>')`. As you can see, the second parameter takes in `$allowable_tags` as in the docs ..

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069916/php-strip-tags-stripping-n-in-text-area-how-to-stop-it) question/answer also.

Perhaps the easiest to get the first few lines then is using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$lines = explode("<br>", $string); // take first 5 from this array by exploding new lines
```

Get the lines of course using `$lines[0]` (1st line), `$lines[1]` (2nd line) etc.

Comment: This is almost working, but $lines is an array which contains empty values and also filled values. Trying to delete the empty values but array_filter($lines) is not working.

Comment: Empty values? you mean you have empty "lines" there too? You said you wanted first 5 lines and this does it. If you want, you can still filter empty lines out by looping trough $lines and when there are 5 of them not empty, break the loop and continue with other work. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes that could be a solution I suppose. If you look at my question I have updated it to show what is happening a.t.m.

Comment: What you have there - are those each a line as they should be?

Comment: Yes they are, but only with explode("\n", $string) and not with the "<br>", but array has empty values.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you mean empty values before/after the line, you can use trim on each line. http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php - is this what you mean?

Comment: No, that explode function is returning this: Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => [5] => [6] => [7] => [8] =>

Dit is een nieuwe test met meerdere regels.
[9] =>

Dit is regel nummer 2.
[10] =>

Comment: It "looks" like there are line breaks in those "empty" values, but I can't seem to get them out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84697/discussion-between-trainoasis-and-cris-kolkman).