# PHP strip_tags stripping new line in ckeditor text area. How to stop it?

Tags: php, ckeditor, string-formatting, strip-tags

I'm using below line to remove text formatting from ckeditor result text area for some reasons.

```
html_entity_decode(strip_tags($result_string_from_ckeditor),ENT_QUOTES,'utf8');
```

It works great except than it stripping new lines and all separate lines will be join to each other.

I tried solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069916/php-strip-tags-stripping-n-in-text-area-how-to-stop-it) and used below line, but no success

```
html_entity_decode(strip_tags(nl2br($result_string_from_ckeditor),'<br>'),ENT_QUOTES,'utf8');
```

**Edit**: for example

ckeditor source text:

```
<p>This is an example</p>

<p>of problem in strip_tags</p>
```

Source result after using command:

```
<p>This is an exampleof problem in strip_tags</p>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm really not sure why you want to do this, but please provide an example of input & output.

Comment: @Dekel, I added an example.

Comment: `strip_tags()` is a very simple and primitive tool and it cannot cope with invalid HTML, modern HTML and possibly some valid HTML. But we'd really need some sample input that reproduces the issue or the question will be impossible to answer.

Comment: BTW, I don't think `utf8` is a valid encoding for [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, actually the `strip_tags` function not so bad with invalid HTML :) it just strip all tags... The problems stars with broken tags/long-named tags, but this is not the case.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, please ignore html_entity_decode and focus on strip_tags behaviour on ckeditor text result.

Comment: @Amir, how does the `<p>` tags still there if you use the `strip_tags` function? something here doesn't really makes sense...

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, `utf8` is not valid, but `utf-8` is. However it's not the problem here...

Comment: The problem is that [I cannot reproduce your results](https://3v4l.org/A2Yn3) with your sample code.

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/<.*?>/', '', $html);`

Comment: @Dekel, i just used source button on ckeditor and copied it here.

Comment: @Amir, the `source` button gives you what you see in the browser, it doesn't mean that this exact data is received by your server. Add `var_dump($result_string_from_ckeditor)` to see the data your server is working on...

Comment: @Dekel Yes, I suppose encoding is not the problem, that's why a only left a comment. But not seeing the warning is a sign of error reporting being misconfigured, which can mask other issues. As you already point out, actual HTML might be different from the OP initially thinks.